# Affine Transform, estimate unknown matrix, 3D

Tags: image-processing, graphics, computer-vision, affinetransform

Let's say the matrix below is in the form  `x' = Mx`. This is the "formula" for a 2D affine transform.

[image]
(source of image is listed [here](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/DevWikiAffineParameters))

**What is the equivalent relation for a 3D Affine transform of 3 points?** (i.e. what does this formula look like for a 3D Affine transform when I have 3 pairs of coordinates?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This image illustrates the equivalent:
[image: 3D Affine Transform]